# How to access the Navigation Drawer Header items from Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I need to access my header items from a Fragment but I can't find a way to do it. I've seen:

```
View headerLayout = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
```

However, I am not working on the NavigationDrawerActivity itself. I have to access it inside a Fragment alone. Is there a way for me to achieve that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's easy! getHeaderView() can be called from an Activity. But, as you are in a Fragment, you just need to getActivity from the Fragment and then call getHeaderView()...

**SOLUTION:**

In your Fragment:

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
```

I hope it helps! Let me know if it didn't work!

Comment: NIce Working Solution ;)

Comment: it is giving me null pointer exception please help